# Error when connecting to MongoDB node.js - client is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I cannot seem to connect to my MongoDB. Here is the error that occurs:

RefernceError : Client is not defined .
at MongoClient.connect ( C:/user/User/desktop/blog app.js
at args.push

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const app = express()


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))


const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var db

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:pass@ds029466.mlab.com:29466/movie-quotes', (err, database) => {
  // ... start the server

   if (err) return console.log(err)
 db = client.db('movie-quotes')
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
  // Note: __dirname is directory that contains the JavaScript source code. Try logging it and see what you get!
  // Mine was '/Users/zellwk/Projects/demo-repos/crud-express-mongo' for this app.
})


app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/')
  })
```

})

Comment: Are you shure you got access to that server?

Comment: yeah its working now. Just had a quick question as to why this tutorial is not using an mvc pattern ? should i put all the routes in app.js  ? or i need to make a controller , model and route folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`database` is your database client. You should use:

```
db = database.db('movie-quotes')
```

instead of:

```
db = client.db('movie-quotes')
```

Comment: also can you please quickly explain to me why some tutorials are using routes , controllers models  and some arent ? im a bit confused and trying to understand what is the proper way..

Comment: The question seems quite wide but I'll try to answer it. Some tutorials use different design patterns (mostly MVC). It is not linked at all with node.js or MongoDB but it is about code architecture. You need to choose the design pattern according to the size and the complexity of your application. Because you said that it is a basic CRUD app, I think an MVC design (routes, controllers, models) seems appropriate and enough for the purpose.

Comment: so writing all your code in app.js without  a routes and controller folder , is MVC design?   also do you have some suggetions on where i can read more about  this? thanks

Comment: That's quite the opposite of what I have written. [MVC Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is about separation. So if you want to implement it, you should not put it all in your `app.js` but as you said in different files or directories. I can suggest you this repository for some [node.js best practices](https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices#1-project-structure-practices).